# FirebaseAuth gives Null pointer exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to register a user in firebase. Here is my code:

App level gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
```

}

Project level gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
```

My code for register user:

```
    private void registerUser(String name,String email,String password) {
    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful()){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Created. Please login.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdf)' on a null object reference
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                  at com.banik.helloworld.SignUpActivity.registerUser(SignUpActivity.java:73)
                  at com.banik.helloworld.SignUpActivity.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:68)
```

I have initialized mAuth in oncreate method of the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    mobileNumber = findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);

    signUpBtn = findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    pBar = findViewById(R.id.signupBar);
}
```

Please help me.......

Comment: mAuth is null. you need to initialize it

Comment: he did its under setContentView

Comment: most probably string name is null

Comment: did u save the text to various email and password other than casting. mean did u give the code `passwordtext =  password.getText().toString();` and u have to pass this passwordtexd to the function

Comment: @Tomin B
Here is my calling 
<code>
registerUser(name.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

Comment: @Shmuel
I initialized in onCreate method.

Comment: @Peter
string are not null. I checked by debug.

Answer (score 0):

You must have **Google Play Services** installed on your phone or emulator.

If you are testing it on the Emulator. 
Try testing it on a real device or make sure you have GPS installed on your emulator and provides a correct longitude and latitude